# Integrate third party plugin using external link in tinymce

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tinymce, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins

I am trying to implement TinyMCE in one of my POC (Angular-Asp.net).
I want to use an external plugin in the TinyMCE editor. Plugin's js file is lying on an external server. When I run the application, it is not loading the plugin's js file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    tinyMCE.init({
      selector: '#mytextarea',

      plugins: [
        'advlist', 'autolink', 'lists', 'link', 'image', 'charmap', 'preview', 'anchor', 'searchreplace', 'visualblocks', 'responsivefilemanager',
        'fullscreen', 'insertdatetime', 'media', 'table', 'help', 'wordcount', 'maths'
      ],
      toolbar: 'undo redo | formatpainter casechange blocks | bold italic backcolor | ' +
        'alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | ' +
        'bullist numlist checklist outdent indent | removeformat | a11ycheck code table help responsivefilemanager',
       
      external_plugins: { name: "responsivefilemanager", url: "https://www.dropbox.com/s/8sltzmhokp4ciw2/plugin.min.js" },
      
      theme: "silver",

      // Theme options
      theme_advanced_buttons1: "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
      theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
      theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
      theme_advanced_buttons4: "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage",
      theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
      theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
      theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
      theme_advanced_resizing: true,

    });
  </script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot host a JS file like that from Dropbox.  You will need to deploy it with your site, or have it hosted via a CDN that allows cross origin requests.